# XFCE with laptop that is often plugged/unplugged to different displays

Tags: xfce, display-settings, hot-plug

at work I was given a ubuntu laptop with gnome and unity. 
However I ran in a few issues, for example the fact that I could not get the screen to lock after some time and other stuff.

As I am a XFCE user at home and I remembered it to be more usable for me, I thought to install the xubuntu package on the laptop as well.

However, I usually plug my laptop to a docking station with 1-2 monitors, as well as pick it up and go to a meeting room.

What I noticed, however, with XFCE is that if I remove the laptop from the docking station and I thus go from 2/3 displays to 1, I cannot access the desktop content that was in the larger screens, because, I believe, the system keeps the configuration as before the unplugging, i.e. expects such content, with icons and the  windows I am working on, to be in the larger screens that are now unplugged.

This is quite disappointing and crippling.

Is there an easy way, easier than going back to gdm/unity, to fix the problem?

Answer (score 1):

Right click on desktop and click open terminal, run `xrandr` command or `arandr` (gui) to configure monitor settings.

You could write a script wrapping `xrandr`.

It's strange that your laptop doesn't detect unplugging. Mime does.
After unplugging, check `xrandr` output for what it think is connected, so we know what is having problem detecting unplug, X or wm.

Comment: I had the problem when connecting via x2go.  with xrandr -s SIZEofMylocalDesktop  I was able to make the "enlarge window to max" work as expected. Not enlarging the window to the size of my normally used screen in the office. Thank you for pointing to xrandr